# Padding changes width inside table

Tags: html, css, html-table, padding

I have a table that has fixed width, and inside the table I need to have some `inputs(text)` that has the same width of the table, but I don't want the text of the inputs to be at `left:0`, I want them to have some padding from the left. But when I put the padding to those inputs the width changes to more than `100%`.

Here the HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="25">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="lalala"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And this is the CSS.

```
table {
    background-color: red;
    width: 300px;
}
table input {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

How can I ensure that the width of the input element is `100%` the width of the table cell?

[Check the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3nk07y1x/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add this css rule to your input:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

> The box-sizing property is used to tell the browser what the sizing
>   properties (width and height) should include.
>
> Should they include the border-box? Or just the content-box.

Here is a snippet:

```css
table {
    background-color: red;
    width: 300px;
}
table input {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="25">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="lalala"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) ([support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing)) in which *"The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin."* in your CSS for the specified elements as @1l13v has done in his answer:

```css
table input {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Or you can use the [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function ([support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)):

```css
table input {
    width: calc( 100% - 10px );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to calculate the width and padding of the input with percentages. If the sum of the content, border, margin, and padding of the element is `100%` then it should fit how you would like. See the `box-model` concept in css: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

> All HTML elements can be considered as boxes. In CSS, the term "box
>   model" is used when talking about design and layout.
>
> The CSS box model is essentially a box that wraps around HTML
>   elements, and it consists of: margins, borders, padding, and the
>   actual content.
>
> The box model allows us to add a border around elements, and to define
>   space between elements.

For example, if you want `10% padding` on the left then the width should be `90%`.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3nk07y1x/1/

CSS:

```
table {
    background-color: red;
    width: 300px;
}
table input { 
    width: 90%;
    padding-left: 10%;
}
```

Comment: @Garmekain did this answer your question? Just wondering if you are looking for something more or if you could mark an answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

The width of the table will be the width plus the padding. Try subtracting some percentage points from the width like this:

```
table input {
  width: 90%;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

I would also change pixels to ems, because these are a little bit more stable on different screen resolutions.